# Can I hash the content of a folder under Windows to check for identical content?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I would like to know if two folders have the same 1:1 identical content. This is because I would like to verify if the copy/backup of my folders is consistent.

How I can do that? How can I compare two folders content-wise nice and quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a diff tool which is capable of diffing folders. I'd say that the most popular one for Windows is [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).

If you need something which'll work from the command line see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732838/folder-comparisons-via-command-line).

**Update**

A more specific answer that is nearly as fast as possible and also very flexible is to use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)'s versions of the Unix command line tools:

```
diff -r dir1 dir2
```

If you want to use a buitin then try [COMP](http://ss64.com/nt/comp.html):

```
forfiles /P %folder1Path% /S /C "cmd /c comp /a @path %folder2Path%\@file"
```

but I warn you that it's messy. For one thing, COMP only works on a single folder so you must handle the recursion yourself (hence the long line). For another it'll prompt after the first comparison is made.

**Update 2**

I do not recommend [doing this](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12626/diff-two-directories-by-finding-and-comparing-the-md5-checksums-of-their-contents.) because it is only going to be faster in certain situations. It will also be incorrect in others. Because you did ask for a faster version, you can also compare just the md5 checksum of the files. You will use Cygwin for this:

```
diff <(sort <(md5deep -r /directory/1/) |cut -f1 -d' ') <(sort <(md5deep -r /directory/2/) |cut -f1 -d' ')
```

This is only going to be of questionable benefit though because it is going to be ran on the host machine either way so we aren't saving bandwidth. It will increase CPU usage. If you break it down though you could create the md5 for files only when saved and only perform the dif part when needed.

Comment: thanks, but I need something faster, possibly not a 1 by 1 comparison .

Comment: The command line versions of this work at the maximum speed of your system pretty much (generally they are only single core apps). WinMerge is also very fast but not suitable for unattended diffs.